# How do I get back the default Samba configuration file (Debian-based system)?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, samba, package-management, config-files

I recently installed Samba and I messed up the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file. How do I get the original configuration back?

Comment: `sudo cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf`

Comment: why is everyone using placeholders for the package name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way (gotten from #ubuntu) is to do this:

```
dpkg-reconfigure <package>
```

In this case that means

```
dpkg-reconfigure samba-common
```

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: `/usr/share/samba/smb.conf` is the original version of the smb.conf file.

When faced with this situation for any package, what I do is one of the following:

1. **Check for backup files of the original version** from your editor.  I use Emacs, which normally leaves `foo~` files, and I've set the numerical version-control option so the original version is always `foo.~1~`.  But maybe you did it some other way, or used some other editor.  Consider checking your editor's configuration to turn this feature on if you haven't already; it's a good habit to get into.
2. **Reconfigure the package** with `dpkg-reconfigure PACKAGENAME`.  Sometimes this does the trick.  In my experience it rarely works; it depends on how the package is creating its configuration files.
3. **Purge and reinstall the package** (with `apt-get purge packagename` followed by `apt-get install packagename`).  This should always work.
   In extreme cases you have to, after purging, manually hunt down and delete the config files before reinstalling the package, but this is rare.  However, this will eliminate any other data and/or config files for the package, and that is not always acceptable.
4. **Download the source code for the package** (`apt-get source foo`) and see if the original config file exist as a file there.  However, it may be that the config file does not exist beforehand, but is created at installation by the package's post-install script.
5. **Check the postinst script for the package** (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/foo.postinst`) to find out where it creates the config file and how it does it.  Then try to repeat the process manually.  This is a bit of work, and not always easy.

Comment: This should be higher. For me it was just a case of doing `sudo cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf` to overwrite my trashed conf file with the original.

Answer (score 8):

**Edited**:

Spotted this on [a serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/82801/linux-how-to-restore-config-file-using-apt-get-aptitude).  If the `dpkg-reconfigure foo` doesn't work, use this:

1. Remove or rename the broken configuration file.

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.broken
   ```
2. Request replacements from `dpkg`.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-confmiss /path/to/samba-common.deb
   ```

This tells `dpkg` to replace missing configuration files with those from the .deb.  You might find the original package .deb in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, or you can use a fresh copy of the same version from your distribution's repositories.

```
dpkg -i --force-confnew foo.deb
```

This tells `dpkg` to overwrite existing configuration files with those from the .deb.  You might find the original package .deb in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, or you can use a fresh copy of the same version from your distribution's repositories.

Comment: That flag only forces `dpkg` to overwrite the config file *if it would otherwise have asked for permission to do so*.  It does **not** make it magically recreate pristine config files from the package.

Comment: i believe you're right.  ok, so you do want the `--force-confmiss` instead.  in this particular case, eg samba, i think `--force-confnew` would perform the overwrite, but you're right that it's dependent on the particulars of the package configuration scripts.

Answer (score 3):

You can restore the original `smb.conf` configuration file like this:

```
# cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf
# dpkg-reconfigure samba-common
```

This is basically what the original package installation process does (on Debian Squeeze).

This will overwrite you current `smb.conf`, so make a backup first if you don't want to lose it.

Comment: Thanks for supplying the name of the package that contains this file.  "sudo aptitude purge samba-common; sudo aptitude install samba" was my choice, but Totor's answer looks the least scary and most Debian of the choices.

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg-reconfigure <package>` will not modify changed conf files by default.

Probably the easiest way to do this, if you still have the package in the apt cache is to run

```
dpgk -i --force-confask /var/cache/apt/archives/<package file name>
```

where the package file name is usually something like `<package name>_<version>.deb` (just use tab completion). This will run through the same process as an apt-upgrade, and ask you what you want to do when ever it finds a changed conf file. Just enter `N` at every prompt. dpkg will install the package version of the conf file with `.dpkg-dist` at the end of the file name. You can then use `vimdiff` or some other merge tool to compare differences, and modify the read conf file.

Comment: There are no packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` though...

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the deb and grab the original file:

```
ar p packagename.deb data.tar.gz | tar zx
```

Comment: Using `dpkg-source` is easier, and using `apt-get source PACKAGE` is *much* easier.

Comment: @Teddy: only if the default config file is included in the source package to begin with.  many packages install a heavily vendor-specific config file; some auto-generate their config files in the `packagename.postinst` script.

Answer (score -2):

```
$ sudo cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

will do the job.

Comment: This is nearly identical to all the other answers here. It's also on a post from '14.